# How do I add scroll onto this div that has onload animation?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, position, overflow

The div that I need to have the ability to scroll is the `timeView` div: I need it to scroll in side the timeholder div and preferrably have a custom scrollbar but that is not necessary. I have tried plugins and css solutions but no one is available. I am preferably looking for a solution in jquery...

```
<aside class="timeContainer">
    <div class="timeHolder">
        <div class="timeView">

<!-- Year Markers -->            
                <div class="yearMarker">1943</div><div class="yearMarker">1944</div><div class="yearMarker">1945</div><div class="yearMarker">1946</div><div class="yearMarker">1947</div><div class="yearMarker">1948</div><div class="yearMarker">1949</div><div class="yearMarker">1950</div><div class="yearMarker">1951</div><div class="yearMarker">1952</div><div class="yearMarker">1953</div><div class="yearMarker">1954</div><div class="yearMarker">1955</div><div class="yearMarker">1956</div><div class="yearMarker">1957</div><div class="yearMarker">1958</div><div class="yearMarker">1959</div><div class="yearMarker">1960</div><div class="yearMarker">1961</div><div class="yearMarker">1962</div><div class="yearMarker">1963</div><div class="yearMarker">1964</div><div class="yearMarker">1965</div><div class="yearMarker">1966</div><div class="yearMarker">1967</div><div class="yearMarker">1967</div><div class="yearMarker">1969</div><div class="yearMarker">1970</div><div class="yearMarker">1971</div><div class="yearMarker">1972</div><div class="yearMarker">1973</div><div class="yearMarker">1974</div><div class="yearMarker">1975</div><div class="yearMarker">1976</div><div class="yearMarker">1977</div><div class="yearMarker">1978</div><div class="yearMarker">1979</div><div class="yearMarker">1980</div><div class="yearMarker">1981</div><div class="yearMarker">1982</div><div class="yearMarker">1983</div><div class="yearMarker">1984</div><div class="yearMarker">1985</div><div class="yearMarker">1986</div><div class="yearMarker">1987</div><div class="yearMarker">1988</div><div class="yearMarker">1989</div><div class="yearMarker">1990</div><div class="yearMarker">1991</div><div class="yearMarker">1992</div><div class="yearMarker">1993</div><div class="yearMarker">1994</div><div class="yearMarker">1995</div><div class="yearMarker">1996</div><div class="yearMarker">1997</div><div class="yearMarker">1998</div><div class="yearMarker">1999</div><div class="yearMarker">2000</div><div class="yearMarker">2001</div><div class="yearMarker">2002</div><div class="yearMarker">2003</div><div class="yearMarker">2004</div><div class="yearMarker">2005</div><div class="yearMarker">2006</div><div class="yearMarker">2007</div><div class="yearMarker">2008</div><div class="yearMarker">2009</div><div class="yearMarker">2010</div><div class="yearMarker">2011</div><div class="yearMarker">2012</div><div class="yearMarker">2013</div><div class="yearMarker">2014</div><div class="yearMarker">2015</div><div class="yearMarker">2016</div><div class="yearMarker">2017</div><div class="yearMarker">2018</div><div class="yearMarker">2019</div>

<!-- End Year Markers -->            

        </div>
    </div>    
</aside>
```

` The CSS:

```
.timeContainer { position: fixed; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 90%; 
    margin: 2% 0% 5% 0%; 
    top: 0px; 
    right: 30px; 
    overflow:hidden;}

.timeHolder { position: absolute; 
    height: 80%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;}

.timeView { position:relative; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 28105px; 
    max-height: 28105px; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    background-image : url(http://ccl.northwestern.edu/extensions/palette/rgb-color-scale-gradient.png);
 background-repeat:repeat-y; 
    background-position: top left; 
    z-index: 90;; 
}

.yearMarker { position:relative; 
    z-index: 91; 
    top:0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    width: 95px; 
    height: 365px; 
    text-align:right; 
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    color: #000; }
```

--------------------------NEXT ISSUE ----------------------------

Ok I have this doc ready animation that moves the timeView div up to the year 2011 (or -24820 px up)

Now the scroll position is now set at the top at the year 2011 and will not scroll up any more

here is the script the init the animation:

```
$('.timeView').animate({
              easing: 'easeInExpo',         
              top: '-=24820px', 
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/GSzZw/33/

Answer (score 0):

setting `top: '-=24820'` is not the same as literal scrolling.  If you want to animate it, animate the scrollTop property I believe.

```
$('#yourDiv').animate({
    scrollTop: -24820
}, 2000);
```

Something like that I'm not quite sure on the syntax, but that will actually scroll the element which will allow you to normal mouse scroll after.  Basically top<>scrollTop

**UPDATE:**

It helps if you try the right div :P.  TimeView isn't the div being scrolled.  Also, use a positive scrollTop value because that will be the same as rolling the wheel mouse down.  You obviously didn't even try to figure this out at all you just tried copying and pasting my solution into yours.  Next time try to think about how the solution offered is applying to your particular problem please.  Anyway, here it is:

```
$('.timeHolder').animate({         
    scrollTop: 24820,
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Nope sorry man it just doesn't work: $('.timeView').animate({         
  easing: 'easeInExpo',
  scrollTop: '-24820px',
}, 10000);